# catch Control+key in Mono C# Readline

Tags: c#, mono, console

Is there a way to catch ctrl+ using Readline() in a Mono console? I'm using Mono 2.10.2 and when I press ctrl-d, for instance, nothing happens. I don't know what signal ReadLine() is getting when I press it.

Answer (score 3):

`ReadLine()` reads a *line of text entered into the console*.

The control key does not have any text representation, so its obvoiusly not "caught". To catch the control key, you can use the `Console.ReadKey()` function.

Here is a sample from the [documentation page for `Console.ReadKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx).

```
  ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
  // Prevent example from ending if CTL+C is pressed.
  Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

  Console.WriteLine("Press any combination of CTL, ALT, and SHIFT, and a console key.");
  Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
  do 
  {
     cki = Console.ReadKey();
     Console.Write(" --- You pressed ");

     if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0)
         Console.Write("ALT+");
     if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) != 0)
         Console.Write("SHIFT+");
     if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
         Console.Write("CTL+");

     Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());
   } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but that won't do. I need to read a whole line of text, but I also need to catch ctrl-d and ctrl-z.

Comment: If you read the documentation, you can use `Console.ReadKey(bool)`, which will allow you to use the code above to detect a `Ctrl+D`, as well as outputting the characters onto the console. There is **no** way you can capture special characters with `Console.ReadLine()`, as explained above.

Comment: I guess I want to catch the "EOF" signal event, rather than CTRL-d.